How to restart a Docker container after changing volume host's path
I have a Docker container running with Docker Compose. I have a secret configured in docke-compose.yml like this:
... 

db:
  image: postgres:13
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/postgresql_password
  secrets:
  - postgresql_password

...

secrets:
  postgresql_password:
    file: postgres_passwd

Now, I have changed the operating system user name and home dir, from user1 to user2.
When I restart the container with docker compose restart, I get this error:

Error response from daemon: Cannot restart container
{CONTAINER_ID}:
failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI
runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container
process: error during container init: error mounting
"/home/user1/apps/app1/postgres_passwd" to rootfs at
"/run/secrets/postgresql_password": stat
/home/user1/apps/app1/postgres_passwd: no such file or directory:
unknown

I understand the error; secret file is no longer in that directory. I wonder if there is a way to restart successfully the container so Docker resolves again the absolute path of the secret file.
Note I have more volumes that I don't want to lose.

You need to delete and recreate the container if you're doing things like changing bind mount directories.  docker-compose up -d should do that automatically for you; does re-running that work?  (You shouldn't usually need start or restart commands.)

When I run docker compose up -d, I get the error: "invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /home/user1/apps/app1/postgres_passwd"

Okay. I had to down it first. docker compose down and docker compose up -d did the job. Thank you!

Instead of using restart, I solved it just running:
$ docker compose down
$ docker compose up -d

WARNING:
Those two commands may remove your containers.
